# how to use notification to call my text field in my another class swift 2.2

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have one  view controller class name `FirstVC.swift`in that i have two `urtext field` called `TF1, TF2`.And i have one custom alamofire class namely `networkinterface.swift" - there is no`ViewDidLoad` in this class and this is for web services. And in that I have one function with uialert.

And for that uialert ok button action , i need to clear the data in my text field.Now in `FirstVC.swift` under `viewDidLoad` i have added this below line :

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("cleardata", object: nil, userInfo:nil);
```

But i don't know how to use my two `textfield` name in my custom alamofire class.

Please help me out how to do that.And how can i clear the data in my textfield, by clicking the action of my button in uialert . I am using swift 2.2

Comment: I suggest you go back a little and learn how to use notifications and then how to handle press of OK button - you combine these two and you get it working :-) both of them are definitely explained here in stackoverflow because I learned it from here.. I also recommend switching to Swift 3, there is no point using Swift 2.2

Comment: can you link some code or tutorial fro so

Comment: @Mazel Tov " I also recommend switching to Swift 3".And how is one supposed to do this then when it hasn't even been released yet.

Comment: @SausageMachine good point, I thought it was Swift 3 what they released, you are right, joke's on me :-D